# Server issues Start-SPServiceInstance not working, but .Provision() Seems to be

Tags: web-services, administration, iis

We are having some pretty severe and bizarre issues. Luckily this is our quality environment. Three server farm. The issue is on the Web-Front-End. Sharepoint 2013 Enterprise. Some of the oddities (they may be normal but when a problem is happening anything looks weird).

1. SharePoint Web Services didn't exist on IIS.(Not sure if Provisioning SharePoint Foundation would recreate this). I had to recreate it with a powershell script. Not sure it completed correctly. Took forever. Followed this link http://blogs.technet.com/b/vinitt/archive/2011/05/14/how-to-get-back-the-sharepoint-webservices-applicaion-in-iis-if-deleted-sharepoint-2010.aspx
2. Microsoft Foundation Web Application would not provision. Usually stuck on Mysites. We had to shutdown the web front end, and clear the cache on the app server, and provision MFWA on that server to keep up the environment.
3. We had two instances of Managed Metadata Service Applications? I think either Deleting one of them or Provisioning the MySites Web application on the web-front-end started the problem.
4. I'm positive there was an issue with mysites, even after doing all this, confirming the web application for mysites was deleted, the database deleted, IIS did not have Mysites in it, `\VirtualDirectories\MysitesQ` still existed. Not confident the 8794 folder was correct, I copied the contents of the App servers 8794 to the front end. I ALSO made sure to delete the timerjob for attempting to Unprovision Mysites.

Anyways, I am slowly trying to bring back up the web-front end. So far `Start-SPServiceInstance` is stuck on Starting and the status is `Provisioning` for every serviceinstance I do.

```
Access Database Service 2010                                  Disabled     663655ad-c118-4eb1-b092-a4a45bc62ccb
Access Services                                               Disabled     d1778f1c-0491-42e6-ad80-0800c1769478
App Management Service                                        Disabled     9a45522f-1d97-439d-99cb-4ea5f81b6f69
Business Data Connectivity Service                            Disabled     fd873fba-7a7b-4c71-972e-951ac84ac9ad
Central Administration                                        Disabled     c8e36329-67f6-4e3f-8785-3bdf3015a297
Claims to Windows Token Service                               Provisioning 49625338-eddc-4be8-b863-3f38334f7369
Distributed Cache                                             Online       01724872-b263-4acf-879d-3aa66420ceed
Document Conversions Launcher Service                         Disabled     7bc5d632-8908-4140-b2a3-ca535031e0ea
Document Conversions Load Balancer Service                    Disabled     aae9609d-7099-423e-b725-1ef31a459c80
Excel Calculation Services                                    Disabled     d7d00a62-5194-4a2b-a176-93d708c4f54a
Lotus Notes Connector                                         Disabled     ce9a37bb-2007-4545-9374-76d5f92d7f86
Machine Translation Service                                   Disabled     b5b61c87-084c-4c70-b9a6-0b1a41bc186f
Managed Metadata Web Service                                  Disabled     6f7a7352-a1de-46b7-83c3-9cef08445886
Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Incoming E-Mail               Disabled     38051b96-8e4c-4cf6-971a-f977db8524fe
Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service        Provisioning 19880128-71a1-4d38-ac6f-79eccc662bd8
Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Subscription Settings Service Disabled     a09db608-b649-42d1-b5a1-c1e31fbdeb70
Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application               Disabled     6795a21f-3d0f-4fca-811f-4d4e0923620b
Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Workflow Timer Service        Online       87991be3-e2b1-4128-8840-686562ddb4af
PerformancePoint Service                                      Disabled     19be761b-b1ed-4470-8a26-634d3955747b
PowerPoint Conversion Service                                 Disabled     23b8ac5f-48f8-474e-b18c-c59f9744d838
Search Host Controller Service                                Disabled     2b42ca2d-6dcc-404a-a7aa-6dec60ef0ea7
Search Query and Site Settings Service                        Disabled     1f2c8ddf-c82b-454b-9ed9-4da8ff165a92
Secure Store Service                                          Disabled     89c4e326-7862-497e-8490-6de046961275
SharePoint Server Search                                      Disabled     1071612d-c7a1-49df-b8a7-85f86d05062d
User Profile Service                                          Disabled     1db0aaa9-8759-4021-aeb2-69d05b0ac773
User Profile Synchronization Service                          Disabled     38d7206c-c80e-49a6-bad3-b0933220b111
Visio Graphics Service                                        Disabled     37dedf91-c8c0-40aa-b429-98c1ffe4c9d7
Word Automation Services                                      Disabled     f15091e6-91e2-4893-837d-53d40c20e6e3
```

So far, The only two that are `Online` are ones that I ran with Start-SPServiceInstance, Gave up, then ran `$serviceInstance.Unprovision()` and then `$serviceInstance.Provision()` each time I cleared the cache, just to be safe. Is this normal?
Is it okay to copy the folder 8794 from the App server to web front end?

We feel like this might be trying to revive the cat from the pet cemetery. Should we even continue, or attempt to reinstall SharePoint?